# avg de cada dia

Tags: mysql

necesito obtener el promedio de cada dia, en un rango de una semana, lo que necesito es que la consulta devuelva 7 filas donde cada fila es 1 dia de la semana

tengo la estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

```
create table mediciones(
    id int  not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    temperatura float not null,
    humedad float not null,
    idvinedo int not null,
    fecha date not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (idvinedo) REFERENCES vinedo(id));
```

y la consulta que tengo es:

> select AVG(temperatura) as temperatura,AVG(humedad) as humedad from
>   mediciones where fecha between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and
>   now() and idvinedo=1

el problema es que me retorna 1 fila con el promedio general de los 7 dias y no cada dia individualmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentalo asi:

```
select fecha, AVG(temperatura) as temperatura,AVG(humedad) as humedad from mediciones 
where fecha between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now() and idvinedo=1
group by fecha
```

Comment: funciona perfecto, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Otra posibilidad (en cuanto a la forma de filtrar por la semana actual) sería escribir la consulta usando **[`YEARWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)** así:

```
SELECT
    fecha, 
    AVG(temperatura) temperatura,
    AVG(humedad) humedad
FROM mediciones 
WHERE 
    YEARWEEK(fecha) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) 
    AND idvinedo=1
GROUP BY fecha
ORDER BY fecha;
```

`YEARWEEK` tiene un aspecto interesante, y es que [admitiría un segundo parámetro `mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) el cual serviría para indicar por ejemplo que quieres que la semana empiece el lunes en vez del domingo:

```
SELECT
    fecha, 
    AVG(temperatura) temperatura,
    AVG(humedad) humedad
FROM mediciones 
WHERE 
    YEARWEEK(fecha,1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(),1) 
    AND idvinedo=1
GROUP BY fecha
ORDER BY fecha;
```